# Правильно по форме, но режет слух

Tags: числительные

...и опять числительные, и опять согласование... по нормам правильно - "тридцать один с половиной миллион человек", но на слух, а это фраза из рекламного ролика, не идет - просится "тридцать один с половиной миллионов человек". Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

"Как быть?"
Придется говорить по правилам. *Миллион* согласуется в данном случае с числительным *один*. Попробуйте всю эту числительную конструкцию поставить в косвенный падеж:
*Нам **тридцати одного с половиной миллиона** не хватит, господа!*
И в именительном падеже - тоже все нормально слышится и пишется.
*В Канаде **проживает** тридцать **один** с половиной **миллион** человек.*

Comment: Спасибо!))) переписал "как правильно"!))))))

Comment: Вместо миллиона - *боров* :  
>М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Помпадуры и помпадурши (1863-1874)  
В 1874 году его свиное стадо заключало в себе двести тридцать **восемь свиней**, тридцать **одного борова** и четыреста поросят.

Comment: Поразительное умение находить нужную цитату в текстах самых разных писателей. Не раз уже молча отмечал это ценное качество. Дерзкий товарищ! (это похвала, а не осуждение!)

Answer (score 0):

"И в именительном падеже - тоже все нормально слышится и пишется. В Канаде проживает тридцать один с половиной миллион человек".

Уважаемый Дерзкий Grantum! 
По-русски так не пишется, Вы уж извините. Тридцать один с половиной (чего?) - миллионА (это р. п.). Миллион - количественное числительное, может быть существительным и тогда склоняется по типу существительных 2-го склонения. Именно "половина" (последнее слово в числительном) здесь управляет зависимым словом "миллиона".